# Remove vertices non-destructively?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, vertices

so my character has a base clothes layer, and a vest layer on top of it. When the vest layer is active, a large part of the base layer is hidden, and so I want to remove the base layer vertices that are hidden to reduce vertices/overdraw in my game.

Right now to do this, I am simply duplicating the base layer mesh, and manually removing vertices that are occluded by the vest layer in the duplicate. But then I have two separate meshes that I need to maintain when it comes to weight painting, etc.

Is there a way I can duplicate a mesh and remove certain vertices non-destructively? So that I can export the mesh for one version containing all of the vertices, and another version with a group of vertices removed? I was thinking of solving this via script, but I wanted to know first if this is possible via modifier or something built-in.

Comment: Not sure.. but would the [Mask modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/mask.html#mask-modifier) fit the bill, here?

Comment: Ah, the Mask modifier is perfecrt! Sorry, I'm a Blender beginner. If you leave an answer I'll select it. Thanks